# How to fetch data from each clusters in k-means

Tags: python, cluster-computing, k-means

Here is my code

## K means Clustering

```
def doKmeans(X, nclust):
    model = KMeans(nclust)
    model.fit(X)
    clust_labels = model.predict(X)
    cent = model.cluster_centers_
    return (clust_labels, cent)

clust_labels, cent = doKmeans(df_new, 4)
kmeans = pd.DataFrame(clust_labels)

df_new.insert((df_new.shape[1]),'clusterNo',kmeans)
```

So there will be 4 clusters, I want to get data for all 4 clusters 
    separately and do further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments to start with. First, after model.fit(X) you can access all labels using model.labels_ . model.predict() can then be used to predict labels on new data. Second, unless you are sure you would not need the model to make predictions on new data it is better for the function to return the actual model as well.

As, for your question you can append the predicted labels to the original data frame and then subset as shown below with or without assigning the result to a new data frame or use other methods like .groupby() to analyse the individual clusters.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

# Data
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ['x', 'y'])


def doKmeans(X, nclust):
    model = KMeans(nclust)
    model.fit(X)
    return (model.labels_, model.cluster_centers_)

clust_labels, cent = doKmeans(X, 2)

df['label'] = clust_labels
df

df[df['label'] == 1]

df
Out[26]: 
   x  y
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  0
3  4  2
4  4  4
5  4  0

df['label'] = clust_labels
df
Out[27]: 
   x  y  label
0  1  2      1
1  1  4      1
2  1  0      0
3  4  2      0
4  4  4      1
5  4  0      0

df[df['label'] == 1]
Out[28]: 
   x  y  label
0  1  2      1
1  1  4      1
4  4  4      1
```